# How to perform database related code in model

Tags: node.js, express

I am .NET developer and learning MEAN stack, developing an API for simple post and comment app. I am using MVC pattern without view as it is API. Here is how I am trying to create my model function :

```
const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);

module.exports.getUsers = function(callback){
    User.find()
        .exec(function(err,list_users){
            if(err) { callback(); }
            return list_users;
        });
}
```

And here is the controller :

```
exports.user_list = function(req,res,next){

    User.getUsers((err,list_users) => {
        if(err){ next(err);}

        res.json({user_list : list_users});
    })
}
```

I am getting an error as `getUsers` is not getting imported.  I am trying here to separate the data access code from controller and make controller only to manage request and response as I have been doing in .NET. Any help how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would look through the documentation to get familiar with how to use mongoose.
First thing I see is that you are not defining the methods correctly according to the documentation here http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods.

But you do not have to define a find() function. Mongoose already has it built in.
So the next step would be how are you creating the instance of the Model in your controller.

Your model should be:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      UserSchema = mongoose.Schema();

const User = new UserSchema({
    // define user
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);
```

And the controller:

```
const User = require('path_to_User_model');
exports.user_list = function(req,res,next){

    User.find((err,result)=>{
        if(err)
            // log err and send response
        else
            // send the result ex: res.json(result);
    });
}
```

also read through the setup on the npmjs website. https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose

So to create have your data functions and have your controller use that function you may try

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      UserSchema = mongoose.Schema();

const User = new UserSchema({
    // define user
});
// data functions
User.methods.getUsers = function (){
    User.find((err,result)=>{
        if(err)
            // log err and return something
            return false;
        else
            return result;
    });
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);
```

then the controller

```
const User = require('path_to_User_model');
exports.user_list = function(req,res,next){
    var users = User.getUsers();

    if (!users)
        res.status(500).send('error_page');
    else
        res.json(users);
}
```

Comment: not defining `find()` function. As you can see, I have created a `getUsers()` inside the model to fetch the data and using same in controller. I know this is not the right way to do it. But what I am trying to achieve is to bind data access functionalities to same model,not in controller. Like `find()` method should be used in model file instead of controller.